# Is it possible to Spoof a TeamViewer ID?

Tags: authentication, remote-desktop, windows-server, teamviewer

I am using 2 forms of remote access to my Windows Server 2008 machine, both go to the Admin account since we only use it to host a Minecraft (MC) Server.

**Remote Desktop**, that goes over a custom port instead of standard, which has a scope to only allow connections from certain IP addresses, and of course the hardware firewall doing the same thing.

**Teamviewer** (up-to-date), which has a whitelist, does not accept connections with a random password, and has a password if you want to change settings in TV.

My question is, **Is it possible to spoof your Teamviewer ID and gain access to a Teamviewer enabled machine?**

This is because as a MC server, we attract a lot of Skiddies, and had few DDoS/DoS attacks  and hacking attempts before, and we want to make sure no one can damage the machine itself.

I considered also scoping the Teamviewer App in Windows firewall, and scope the hardware firewall to certain IP addresses too, but the reason we have TV is to gain access when we are NOT at home, thus connecting from different IP addresses each time, so that would not be a move we want to take.

Are there any more things I could do to protect myself from unauthorized server access? We do not host anything else than the MC server, and the only apps that are not blocked by our firewall are a few plugins for the MC server, MC itself, the browser, TV, remote access and windows updates, the rest is nailed shut.

Comment: Windows Server 2007 isn't an operating system. Did you mean 2003, 2008, or 2008 R2? ;)

(not that it really matters)

Comment: Yea, 2008, i forgot what the number was and guessed right out of the blue, thanks ;3

Comment: Sidenote : if you only host an MC server I recommend switching to a GNU/Linux OS.

Comment: @AndréDaniel We chosed to use a windows server OS instead of linux because of the GUI and native functions and communications with our secured NAS and own computers, it is far easier to manage, secure and work on the server through a Windows OS than linux, in our case.

Comment: @Lighty it's your choice, but in my opinion a GUI on a server is pretty useless and uses some resources that can be put to better use (allotted to the game server itself in your case).

Comment: @AndréDaniel the server that we run has regular maintnance, and we work ALOT on it, we prefer the GUI because we don't feel like poking around in multiple configs of multiple plugins in a command line, but a structured, stable GUI that works when it needs to, no extra actions needed, its called usability, even for pro's in the field of MC Servers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the TeamViewer ID is provided by the TeamViewer servers.  The attacker would have to emulate the entire TeamViewer protocol in order to spoof the ID.  They would have to act as both the TeamViewer servers in the middle, as well as connecting client itself in order to make your system believe that it was a legitimate TeamViewer connection.

Comment: this awnsers a big part of the question indeed! but the question if i could protect myself better is still ingering, well, its more of a question for superuser, but this awnser relieves alot, thanks!

Comment: I think you've got yourself pretty locked down.  Strict firewall rules and weekly patch updates is the best you can do from a network security standpoint.

Comment: Taking this one step further, restricting TeamViewer traffic to the official server farms won't impact the ability to connect from new locations, as long as the official proxy is used.